# How to use retrofit library

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded the retrofit library and samples from https://github.com/square/retrofit.I want to do image and data caching.
But I am not getting how to use that in android.Can Somebody give me an example.I have checked the code

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setServer("")     
        .build();
```

ClientInterface service = restAdapter.create(ClientInterface.class);

Callback callback = new Callback() {

```
@Override

public void success(Object o, Response response) {
    // Read response here
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    // Catch error here
} }; 
service.findBuffet("sudhakar", callback);
```

But I am not getting anything.
Thanks for the help in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an interface like below.

```
public interface MyService {
  @GET("/getUser/{user}")
  User getUserDetails(@Path("user") String userId);
}
```

Create your rest adapter

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://mybaseurl.com")
    .build();

MyService service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
```

Get user details like this:

```
User user = service.getUserDetails("123456");
```

**To get a successful result you have to define your pojos correctly.** 
You can use this link to create your pojos : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Can you do me a favor please.Can you write a full code how to  call the rest api and traverse the json.

Comment: It's already above. Just change the endpoint with your rest api url and modify MyService interface with your api method and it's parameters. Create your rest adapter and use it like the third code block in my answer.

Comment: I apologize,but I am not getting anything.It will be best for me if you can give me a full complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is best to use. follow are the steps to use retrofit. 
Please [get details process here](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/course/ecommerce-android-app-development/lessons/send-data-using-retrofit-library/)

**Step 1**- add dependency

**Step 2** - init retrofit and add wrapper functions to call interface

**Step 3** - Create POJO model using any online jsoneditor like jsoneditor.org

**Step 4** - Create interface (URL from where you want to fetch date)

**Step 5** - Call wrapper function from activity.